# What are the ways to manage a large guild in terms of activity and representativeness?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm part of a large guild, oftenly full (500 members) and with 100~150 online. Officers find it very difficult to track who is active and representing the guild, is there any way to track down these informations in order to track inactive players?

Comment: Only manually - maybe set all new recruits/non-officers/non-reps to a new lower rank, and only raise them to the regular rank if they're active, and then occasionally purge the inactive ones?

Comment: Many guilds have forums on which you register with your account name. They then enforce a weekly login to the forums as a way of judging activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'd probably know, you can track who is currently online but not representing your guid simply by looking at the guild window: a little green square next to a guild member's name means "online and representing", a green square with a horizontal grey line through it means "online but not representing", and a grey square means offline (of course they could be on using the "invisible" status and you wouldn't know whom they're representing).

- If your guild requires *exclusive representation* (personally, I'm not a fan of this), you could just get your officers to occasionally scroll through the list and kick out anyone "caught" not representing.
- If you only require occasional representation with occasional activity, it gets a bit harder. The information in the history tab of the guild window only shows how many members logged in on a given date and how many influence that earned as well as how many activities they completed while representing your guild and how much that earned. Unless someone purchased a letter of commendation or similar, you won't see who is responsible for raising influence.

Going with the option David suggested in the comments could easily be abused. If I leave a browser tab open and set it to auto-load every few hours, I can make it seem like I'm an active guild member without ever playing the game.

Gwen's suggestion could perhaps be used to create ranks similar to the following:

- A rank just above officer for those who "patrol" for activity
- A member rank for "active in past x days" for new recruits or lower ranks found to be active
- A rank below that for "active in past 2x days"
- A rank at the bottom for "inactive, please whisper patrol to save your membership..."

This could be adjusted depending on how much manual maintenance you want the patrols to do every x days, but you get my drift. It would probably be fair to put up a Message of the Day to explain this.